# Sending keyboard input to a program from command-line

Tags: linux, user-interface, shell, keyboard, ipc

How do you send keyboard input to a program?

That is, under a Linux GUI, is there a good manual (programmable) way, or tool,
of simulating keyboard input on a running program on Linux, so that I can send
from the command-line, e.g., "Control-T" to a Firefox process and "echo
'hello'\n" to a Gnome-Terminal process without actually focusing on each of
those processes and typing in directly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`xdotool` does have a way of sending keystrokes if limited to a focused window:

```
WID=`xdotool search "Mozilla Firefox" | head -1`
xdotool windowactivate $WID
xdotool key ctrl+l
```

Comment: List of key symbols you can find in `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` file.

Comment: Online Documentation can be found here: http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/

Comment: Why do you use `head -1`?

Comment: stumbled here for a list of keys, updating comments. Most people don't install dev packages so list here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/keysyms.htm , and head -n 1 is normally used to get the first match in case you have multiple

Answer (score 3):

It's an old topic, but one still may be looking for this, someone mentioned here solution where window must be activated when using xdotool. However you can specify window and even use xdotool to find it. Here is example I tried to accomplish, change it as you need.

```
xdotool key --window $(xdotool search --name "Spotify (Premium |Free )?- Linux Preview" | head -n1) ctrl+KP_Down
```

Comment: Didn't work from me, I tried with Audacity `xdotool key --window $(xdotool search --name "Audacity" | head -n1) Ctrl+Q`

Answer (score 2):

I've built a [Ruby DSL](https://github.com/NSinopoli/mani) around `xdotool` to simplify the focusing of windows and simulation of keyboard input. Here's an example, riffing on your original request:

```
Mani.new(window_manager: :xmonad) do
  window :hello, launch: 'urxvt' do
    run 'echo "hello\n"'
  end

  window :firefox, launch: 'firefox', delay: 1.5 do
    type '{{ctrl+t}}'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found these two programs [xmacro](http://xmacro.sourceforge.net/) and [xremote](http://chakie.infa.fi/xremote/) you may take a look, but it seems that they're not well documented.

I also found this utility `xvkbd` in answer to this question SO Q&A titled:  [Sending keycode to Xorg + wine with bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954779/sending-keycode-to-xorg-wine-with-bash-script).