# How to cleanly shutdown Eclipse from Linux command line?

Tags: linux, eclipse, command-line, kill, workspace

Is there a way to shutdown Eclipse cleanly from the command line, such that files and workspaces are saved? kill -3 doesn't do anything. kill -1 and kill -15 (default) causes Eclipse to exit abruptly with JVM termination popup. kill -9 does the same thing.

The use case is that I'm working remotely on a machine with Eclipse loaded on it, and I want to save memory by closing Eclipse, but I want Eclipse to save its state first.

I could use VNC or some alternative desktop sharing software, but that's really heavy-weight, and I'd much prefer a command line solution.

EDIT: System info: RHEL5.1 64-bit using GNOME

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any added `ShutdownHooks` ([more info here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29)) should be executed by the JVM when terminated by `SIGTERM`. Therefore, I think the problem is the way Eclipse is programmed to deal with such signals.

As I don't know how the cleanup process is implemented in Eclipse, I can only assume that it is not called by any `ShutdownHook` (and rather by an `Action` or something similar).

Edit: pidge has provided [an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12870625/79595) however which details steps which should allow you to shutdown Eclipse cleanly from the command line.

Comment: This is right.  A plugin developer could write a plugin to listen on a socket for a close command, and call `IWorkbench.close()`.  Or eclipse and the launcher could be updated to support more than just the openFile action.  But there's nothing that comes with eclipse by default.

Comment: today I just call $ kill pid

Comment: kill -HUP pid works well for me. This gets eclipse to shutdown but still gives it a change to delete all its lock files etc.

Answer (score 43):

I figured this out with the help of [gigi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6391853/421297) and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3800208/421297). You're going to need the [`wmctrl`](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/) and [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) utilities from your package manager.

Unless you're running in a terminal emulator on the same display, you need to set the right display:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Then (irrelevant windows elided from example):

```
# List windows
$ wmctrl -l
...
0x030000fa  0 kcirb Java - Eclipse

# Tell Eclipse window to close gracefully
$ wmctrl -c eclipse

# Darn, there's a confirmation dialog
$ wmctrl -l
...
0x030000fa  0 kcirb Java - Eclipse 
0x03003c2d  0 kcirb Confirm Exit 

# Send return key to the window
$ xdotool key --window 0x03003c2d Return
```

Worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04, at least.

EDIT: See [Scarabeetle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14623811/421297) for the tweaks you need to make it work from a script.

Comment: thanks! That worked perfect. One minor point of improvement `xdotool search Exit` is unnecessary as it returns the decimal form of `0x03003c2d`. You can directly use the hex Window ID from `wmctrl -l` like `xdotool key --window 0x03003c2d Return` and skip the search step.

Answer (score 7):

Not enough reputation to comment on [pidge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12870625/1697540) above...
It almost works, but I needed to wait for some Gnome3 animation to finish and then give focus to the "Confirm Exit" window:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0        # Do this in main X session
wmctrl -c "Eclipse SDK"    # Close main window
sleep 1                    # Wait for animation
wmctrl -a "Confirm Exit"   # Give focus to the dialog
# Send a Return keypress to press the OK button
xdotool key --window $(xdotool search "Confirm Exit") Return
```

Answer (score 3):

Try killing java process(es). Do `ps -ea | grep java`

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried with wmctrl?
wmtrl -l
lists the windows and
wmlctrl -c -P 
should close the window.
Anyway you could have problems with the confirmation dialog of eclipse.

Comment: Installed it and twiddled with it a bit. Didn't work remotely (via ssh shell). Locally, it doesn't even list the eclipse window. Maybe I'm just using it wrong?

Comment: You need to set the DISPLAY environment variable `export DISPLAY=:0.0` if you're running the command remotely. See my answer for a walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `kill -HUP` (`kill -1`)? -- that's the canonical way to tell a process that whoever was interacting with it has gone away and it should clean up appropriately

Comment: Nope that didn't work - Eclipse exits abruptly (JVM termination msg pops up).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was helpful to me in a similar issue: [Eclipse hanging, how to kill it properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961850/eclipse-hanging-how-to-kill-it-properly)

After I killed the eclipse process the Eclipse window kept there until I killed the java process (I didn't have a javaw process as in the answer above. I had only one "java" process that when killed fixed the problem).