# Eclipse hanging, how to kill it properly?

Tags: eclipse

Sometimes my Eclipse hangs and I need to kill it violently. However, I have been unable to do it properly. It seems that kill -9  does not actually shut it down in a proper way since I can still see the hanged window. What command sequence would kill my Eclipse properly so I could restart it?

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 and Eclipse 4.2(Juno).

Comment: have you tried xkill? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xkill

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to kill the `javaw` process on which Eclipse runs (usually it is the one with about 1GB memory usage :) )

Comment: As of Luna (and possibly earlier), Eclipse shows up as "eclipse.exe" in Task Manager.

Comment: @Dan1701 ubuntu he said

Comment: look for the process "java":
sudo ps -A | grep java
and then run:
sudo kill xxxx
where xxxx is a pid number of the process

Comment: Update: On Ubuntu 14.10 the process name is changed to `java`

Answer (score 37):

You can also use `jps -l` to get all of the process id's of java processes

Comment: Doesn't work for me because it is not installed on my Ubuntu machine, "Command 'jps' not found".

Comment: @Eric install openjdk

Answer (score 6):

Based on the answer of Uku and Michael you can do the following:

On your terminal first run:

```
jps -l
```

Check the pid of the process that is running Eclipse and copy the pid.

Then kill the process id by running:

```
// use the actual process id
kill -p {the_copied_pid}
```

Comment: This gave me the error `bash: kill: p: invalid signal specification`

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo : kill -9 {the_copied_pid}