# Sending keystrokes or text to a program running with wine

Tags: bash, shell, wine

I'm starting a windows-program with wine in a shell script. Now I would like to pass keystrokes and texts to it. I've tried `xvkbd` as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954779/sending-keycode-to-xorg-wine-with-bash-script) question, but the program just outputs the letter/text into the terminal and exits after that. Here's an example:

```
`wine BERCon.exe > output.txt &`
sleep 5;
`xvkbd -text "N"`
```

Is that even possible to do? I checked the man-page of `xvkbd` to check if I can change the focus somehow, but it seems like thats not possible.I noticed that if I do something like `echo "N" | wine BERCon.exe` the N actually gets passed to wine and wine puts it into the program, but gets into a loop after that and continues to input that letter.